# Is there After Kafka Transaction Commit hook (similar technique) to process application logic for resource cleanup?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, transactions, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We have requirement, where we need to do some resource clean up after kafka transaction is committed. This is java spring application and we are using spring cloud stream kafka library for implementing kafka transaction.  I was wondering, if there is any hook or callback from kafka transaction coordinator after transaction is committed where application can run some logic?

Currently we are depending on ProduceListener onSuccess method to clean up the resource. However recently we realize that it is callback from broker (ack from broker) and not after transaction committed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any such hook. I checked the entire source code for the spring Kafka transaction manager and there's none. Also, the ack from a broker is the reliability guarantee that your records are committed properly because it could happen on the producer side you produced but the process crashed before the data was sent to the broker and you released the resource.

I am not entirely sure what is your flow but if you want to release the resource once the data is sent you could do that because the producer has retry strategies also which will retry to send the message or else what you are currently doing is enough